# Calculate approximately the expression $A = 5^{1/2} . 5^{1/4} . 5^{1/8}...$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, radicals

Calculate approximately the expression $A = 5^{1/2} \cdot 5^{1/4} \cdot 5^{1/8}\cdot\ldots$

My books says to says to do this:

$ 5^{1/4} \cdot 5^{1/8} \cdot 5^{1/16}\cdot\ldots = A    $

Then

$ A = \sqrt {5A} \Longrightarrow A^2 = 5A \Longrightarrow A =5    $

Why $ 5^{1/4}\cdot 5^{1/8}\cdot 5^{1/16}\cdot\ldots = A    $ ??

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you have typos at exponents.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's because initially $A$ had $5^{1/2}$

Comment: Oh I see; in the first line you have set $A$ to be $A = 5^{1/2} \cdot 5^{1/4} \cdot 5^{1/8}\cdot\ldots$. In that case, it is *not* true that $5^{1/4}\cdot 5^{1/8}\cdot 5^{1/16}\cdot\ldots = A$ (the former is $5$, and the latter is $5/\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{5}$). Either the book has a typo, or you copied it wrong. My guess is that the book meant to say that $$5^{1/4}\cdot 5^{1/8}\cdot 5^{1/16}\cdot\ldots = \sqrt{A}.$$
This is true because taking square roots means each of the exponents is halved ($\frac12$ becomes $\frac14$, and $\frac14$ becomes $\frac18$, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are asking why $A=\sqrt{5A}$?

Since 
$$5A=5^1\cdot 5^{1/2}\cdot 5^{1/4}\cdots,$$
we have
$$\sqrt{5A}=(5A)^{1/2}=5^{1/2}\cdot 5^{1/4}\cdot 5^{1/8}\cdots=A.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$5^{1/2} 5^{1/4}\cdot5^{1/8}\cdot5^{1/16}... =5^{\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}}$$

As the power of $5$ are in infinite Geometric Progression with common ratio $=\frac12<1$

$$\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac12}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

You are considering the infinite product $$A = \prod_{k=1}^\infty 5^{1/2^k} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n 5^{1/2^k}.$$
In order to calculate the limit, we have to be sure that the limit exists. This is the case in your example, as we can see by taking the logarithm: $$\log(\prod_{k=1}^n 5^{1/2^k}) = \sum_{k=1}^n\log(5^{1/2^k}) = \log(5) \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k} \text{converges for }n\to \infty.$$

Considering partial product, we find that $$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n 5^{1/2^k} \right)^2 = \prod_{k=1}^n 5^{2/2^k} = \prod_{k=1}^n 5^{1/2^{k-1}} = 5\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} 5^{1/2^k}.$$ Taking limits $n\to\infty$ on both sides gives $A^2 = 5A$. Note that this does not show $A = 5$ immediately, as $A=0$ would be another solution to the equation. But all powers of $5$ are $>1$, therefore $A>1$ and hence $A=5$ is the only remaining solution.

**Why is it important that the limit exists?**

We have concluded $A^2=5A$ by taking limits on both sides of an equation. But the non-existence of both limits is also a possible result in general. Take for example:  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n = 1+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n. \\ \not \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n = -1.$$Apparently, something went wrong. The problem is exactly that the limits on both sides of the equation do not exist. We have to be very careful when dealing with infinity!

Answer (score 2):

Because when you take square roots, you have to divide the exponent by $2$.

Clearly your book wants you to solve this by setting up an equation for the answer and finding the answer. The direct way would be
$$
5^{1/2}\cdot 5^{1/4} \cdots = 5^{1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots} = 5 ^1 = 5$$